# What python object-type is compatible with the ms-access date/time field?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, python-datetime

I have a piece of code that tries to insert a `datetime.datetime` into an ms-access datebase's `date/time` (not `extended date/time`) field, yet I keep getting the data type mismatch error message.
So my question is, which type do I use for this?

I tried using this code

```
    print(type(timeCET))
    >>>
    datetime.datetime
```

and

```
    crsr.execute("insert into WeatherAnalisis(Time_UTC) values ('timeCET.timedate')")
    cnxn.commit()
    >>>>
    pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (-3030) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: which module is `timeCET` imported from ?

Comment: I thought that it would be clear from the top bit of code, but it is from `datetime`.

Comment: i dont see that function in the `datetime` module which is why i ask..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You directly included the *name* of your datetime object as a quoted literal in SQL statement. As a result, Access throws an error since your are trying to insert a literal string value `'timeCET.timedate'` (the *name* and not value of your actual datetime variable) into datetime column.

Instead, consider SQL parameterization. (Do not concatenate as single quotes will not work to enclose dates in Access SQL).

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARK
sql = "insert into WeatherAnalisis (Time_UTC) values (?)"

# EXECUTE QUERY WITH BINDED PARAM
crsr.execute(sql, timeCET)
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: It doesn't spitt any errors at me, but now it adds it to the end instead of replacing the old ones

Comment: That is what `insert` queries do. If you need to replace, use an `update` query. But your original question of data type mismatch should be resolved. Correct?

Comment: Yes, thanks I marked your answer

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the original question does not specify where the variable `timeCET` originates from, once can see that it is a `datetime` from its type.

The problem seems to be one of `matching types`.

Given this, here is how to convert to a string:

```py
import datetime as dt


# create a datetime
t = dt.datetime.utcnow()
print(t)
print(type(t))


# now convert to string
u = t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print(u)
print(type(u))
```

This is the output:

```
2022-03-26 17:00:52.998699
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
03/26/2022, 17:00:52
<class 'str'>
```

The original type (for variable `t`) was `datetime`.

This is now changed (for variable `u`) to `string`.

This can now be parsed into the database (or changed to a format that works).